# view xml file in emacs

Tags: emacs, cygwin, xml

I'm using Cygwin xEmacs 24.5. My goal is to view xml file nicely formatted.

First I opened it using `nxml-mode` or `xml-mode` and it was OK to view it.
Then I somehow 'played' with schema and I assume I broke it because now when I try to open xml file in `nxml-mode` or `xml-mode` it is not formatted at all, 
it states (nXML Valid) and it states "Using vacuous schema"

Question:
How could I restore it? My goal is just to view xml file properly formatted.

Comment: Undo whatever you did when you played with schema.

Comment: well ... I don't know what should I 'undo' :)
I also noticed that if I open that file in Browser or Notepad++ it has nice formatting but in Emacs it's not.